# Como dar validar fechas en javascript o jquery , independientemente del formato de fecha del PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Estoy validando 2 fechas (fecha inicio y termino)
en campos tipo input type=date
la función para validar la tengo en javascript en un archivo js

aquí el codigo de la validación
validar.js

```
function ConvertirStringToDate(fechaString)
{
var fechas = fechaString.split('/');
if (fechas.length != 3)
    fecha = fechaString.split('-');

var tipoDate = new Date(fechas[2], fechas[1], fechas[0]);


return tipoDate;
}


function ValidarFiltroDeFechas(stringFechaDesde, stringFechaHasta) {

    stringFechaDesde=document.getElementById(stringFechaDesde).value;
    stringFechaHasta=document.getElementById(stringFechaHasta).value;

    Validador = { Estado: true, Mensaje: '' };

    if (stringFechaDesde == "") {
        alert("Debe ingresar una fecha de inicio.");

    }

    if (stringFechaHasta == "") {
        alert("Debe ingresar una fecha de término.");

    }

    var dateDesde = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaDesde);
    var dateHasta = ConvertirStringToDate(stringFechaHasta);

    if (dateDesde > dateHasta) {
        alert("La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor a la de término.");
    }
}
```

Acá el codigo html de ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="valida.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>F inicio</label><input type="date" id="fechaInicio">
<label>F termino</label><input type="date" id="fechaTermino">
<button type="button" onclick="ValidarFiltroDeFechas('fechaInicio','fechaTermino')">Validar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Funcionamiento

Esta función me valida correctamente cuando los campos fecha inicio y termino están vacíos, o si cualquiera de los 2 está vacío. Pero cuando quiero validar que la fecha de inicio no sea mayor a la de termino, no se valida y que el input date captura la fecha del equipo, y yo tengo configurada la fecha como dd/mm/yyyy y la validación de fecha inicio mayor a fecha termino solo funciona si coloco la fecha como YYYY/MM/DD. y quiero saber como podría hacer para que se valide sin importar que formato de fecha tenga mi PC.

validar fechas vacías
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora al validar fecha inicio mayor a termino no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora dejo el campo como input text e ingreso la fecha manual con formato YYYY/MM/DD, entonces ahi si valida.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacer para que validara igual independientemente del formato de fecha? o en ultimo caso si es que no se pudiera, como le puedo dar formato al input date para que muestre el formato que necesito sin tener que cambiar el formato de fecha de mi PC?

Comment: No me funciona tu codigo...

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias soluciones aquí, primero, creo que tu función `ConvertirStringToDate` esta de mas si lo que quieres es solo validar las fechas.

Si tu dejaras de utilizar tu función y solo compararas tus fechas como vienen desde tus `input` lo valida correctamente:

```
var dateDesde = stringFechaDesde;
var dateHasta = stringFechaHasta;

if (dateDesde > dateHasta) {
    alert("La fecha de inicio no puede ser mayor a la de término.");
}
```

La otra opcion es usando tu función `ConvertirStringToDate`, ahorita te lo manda como invalid date, por que tu funcion recibe un formato de fechas así 2019-04-02(AAAA-MM-DD) y tu en el split quieres buscar el "/" pero no lo encuentra, lo que deberias de buscar es el "-" para que separé tu cadena y ahora si convierta la fecha correctamente:

```
function ConvertirStringToDate(fechaString)
{
var fechas = fechaString.split('-');
if (fechas.length != 3)
    fecha = fechaString.split('/');

var tipoDate = new Date(fechas[2], fechas[1], fechas[0]);


return tipoDate;
}
```

Espero y te sirva, y sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias , revisaré y te cuento.